# Differentiating between post and param variables in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, post, zend-form-element

I have this code in one of my helpers

```
 $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
 $request = $front->getRequest();  
 print_r($request->getParams());
```

result

```
Array
(
    [controller] => packaging
    [action] => index
    [package] => 87
    [module] => default
    [groupid] => 32
    [packageid] => 87
    [conceptrel] => 161
    [always_same] => 
    [getparts] => 1
)
```

Here some times the packageid comes via POST and sometimes via url(getparam)..how can i know whether its post or param ?

Comment: You can also call `getPost('packageid')` or `getQuery('packageid')` on the request to only access POST or GET vars respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer

```
$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$request = $front->getRequest();
print_r($request->getUserParams()); //only user params not post,get..etc
```

Answer (score 1):

to answer the question you asked:

> *how can i know whether its post or param ?*
>
> **24.4.2.3**. Determining the Request Method getMethod() allows you to determine the HTTP request method used to request the current
>   resource. Additionally, a variety of methods exist that allow you to
>   get boolean responses when asking if a specific type of request has
>   been made:
>
> isGet()
>
> isPost()
>
> isPut()
>
> isDelete()
>
> isHead()
>
> isOptions()

so this results in code like:

```
if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
    //do some stuff
}
```

Comment: if im right..$this->getRequest()->isPost() is supported only in action not in helper

Comment: if you have access to the request object you should have access to all the request methods. So if you can call ->getParams() you should also be able to call ->isPost().

Answer (score 0):

You can check first if the request is post `$request->isPost();`

As for origin, you could write a helper for that as well. The `getParams` method in `Zend_Controller_Request_Http` returns first user parameters, then GET, then POST. The last one of those is preferred when the names match. Your helper would have to take that into account.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like this:

```
$this->getRequest()->setParamSources(array('_POST'));
```

and your `$_POST` array will always be equal to `getParams()`;